# Why replacing constructor function's prototype is not reflected in the Objects?

Tags: javascript

if I just use obj.prototype.property = val, everything will be ok, code like

```
function animal() {}
var frog = new animal();
animal.prototype.color = 'Green';
console.log(frog.color);
// 'Green'
```

But if I use `obj.prototype = {key:val}` after new keyword, it will give me a `undefined`, code like

```
function animal() {}
var frog = new animal();
animal.prototype = {
    color: 'Green'
};
console.log(frog.color);
// 'undefined' -- why?
```

And if I change the order which let the prototype before the new keyword, it will be ok, so weird and why? because we know an object’s prototype allows us adding properties to all instances of that object (even to the existing instances), right?

code like

```
function animal() {}
animal.prototype = {
    color: 'Green'
};
var frog = new animal();
console.log(frog.color);
// 'Green'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS prototype objects not inherited?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970431/js-prototype-objects-not-inherited)

Comment: The following answer may help you understand the role of prototype and constructor functions. Your question is already answered but putting an instance specific property on the prototype is an indication you may not understand what prototype is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new Object with `new` keyword, the newly created object's internal `[[Property]]` object will be set to the constructor function's prototype object.

```
function animal() {}
var frog = new animal();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(frog) === animal.prototype);
# true

animal.prototype = {
    color: 'Green'
};

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(frog) === animal.prototype);
# false

console.log(frog.color);
```

In the first `console.log`, it prints `true` because, `new` has set the `animal`'s `prototype` object as the `frog`'s internal `[[Prototype]]` object. But, when you assign some other object to `animal`'s `prototype`, `frog`'s internal `[[Prototype]]` object still refers to the old object, which doesn't have `color` property. That is why it is printing `undefined`.

When you change the order, when `new` statement is encountered, it gets the `animal`'s `prototype` object (which is the new object you assigned), and creates the `frog` object. That is why it has `color` property.

Now, you might be wondering why the first case is working fine. Because,

```
animal.prototype.color = 'Green';
```

is not replacing `animal.prototype` with some other object, but it mutates (or augments, if you prefer) the `animal.prototype` object. So, `frog`'s internal `[[Prototype]]` property is still the same as the `animal.prototype` object.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning a brand new object. `prototype` is not the `[[Prototype]]` of an object. `new` uses this property to set up the internal property. So what happens is that the reference to the `prototype` object that `new` uses, is not the same as the object you assigned later. You shouldn't override the `prototype` property, always extend it, like in your first example:

```
function Animal(){}
var frog = new Animal();
Animal.prototype.color = 'green';
console.log(frog.color); // green
```

Comment: Because if you assign a new `prototype` object first, then `new` will grab that new object. If you do it later, then it is too late, `new` already used the `prototype` property that the function has by default.

Comment: thx Mr. White, you say shouldn't override the prototype? but assigning a {} to prototype is very convenient, if not, I'll make prototype.a, prototype.b again and again

Comment: Ok, but this is not about convinence, it is about the effects, as you saw. What you can do is `extend(Animal.prototype, {color: 'green'})` and get `extend` from npm, or underscore or something.